# Why does my UITableView fail to scroll unless I tell it to animate the scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've set up a table view so that it will scroll to a certain row when its view controller loads.  I put this code into the viewDidLoad method, and it works how I expect it:

`[thisTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:16 inSection:0] 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];`

However, if I change that last bit to `animated:NO`, it doesn't scroll at all.  I'm fine with having it animate, but I'm wondering: why doesn't it scroll if animated is set to NO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In viewDidLoad, your tableView is empty, scrolling to row 16 is then not possible. The call is evaluated immediately because no need for animation

When you use animated:YES, the animation is delayed until the view is displayed, your table is populated by then.

You may want to use this kind of code in viewDidAppear (or viewWillAppear) instead, when your table has already been populated with data.
This will call it every single time the view is presented though (unless you add some logic), not sure if that meets your requirement...

Comment: Perfect.  It works as I wanted exactly.  Also that helps a lot to know the tableView doesn't actually load until after viewDidLoad finishes. Thanks

Comment: Also, as a side note, I forced the table to load its data in viewDidLoad by calling reloadData on the table view.  This made scrolling without animation work in viewDidLoad

Comment: If this is a static table, why not, but otherwise, it's just not the right place to do that. Also, in case you see a display glitch from using viewDidAppear, you can use viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: Right, I figured that's not really what you want to do.  Putting it in viewDidAppear is what I should have done in the first place.